Java: Constructor undefined?
I am writing a scheduling program for school. The driver (Project3.java) calls for class schedules to be run. I have to write the classes (FirstComeFirstServe, ShortestJobFirst, Priority, RoundRobin, and PriorityRoundRobin). My issue is with the last two classes I made, RoundRobin and PriorityRoundRobin. I cannot change any of the code in Project3.java per instructions. However, I am getting these errors:
error on Project3.java
Here is how I set up RoundRobin and PriorityRoundRobin:
public class PriorityRoundRobin implements Algorithm {
    private List<Task> taskList;   // List of tasks to be scheduled
    private int timeQuantum;       // Time quantum for round-robin scheduling

    // Constructor: Pass task list to create an instance of this class
    public PriorityRoundRobin(List<Task> taskList) {
        this.taskList = new LinkedList<>(taskList);  // Copy task list for manipulation
    }

    // Set the time quantum outside of the constructor
    public void setTimeQuantum(int timeQuantum) {
        this.timeQuantum = timeQuantum;
    }

    @Override
    public void schedule() {
        while (!taskList.isEmpty()) {
            Task nextTask = pickNextTask();  // Get the next task with the highest priority

            if (nextTask != null) {
                int burstTime = nextTask.getBurst();  // Get the burst time of the task

                // If the burst time is greater than the time quantum
                if (burstTime > timeQuantum) {
                    CPU.run(nextTask, timeQuantum);  // Run task for time quantum
                    nextTask.setBurst(burstTime - timeQuantum);  // Reduce burst time by time quantum
                    taskList.add(nextTask);  // Re-add the task to the end of the list
                } else {
                    CPU.run(nextTask, burstTime);  // Run task for remaining burst time
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Task pickNextTask() {
        if (taskList.isEmpty()) {
            return null;  // No more tasks
        }

        // Sort the tasks based on priority (lower priority value = higher priority)
        taskList.sort((task1, task2) -> Integer.compare(task1.getPriority(), task2.getPriority()));

        return taskList.remove(0);  // Remove and return the first (highest-priority) task in the list
    }
}

==============================================================================================
public class RoundRobin implements Algorithm {
    private List<Task> taskList;  // List of tasks to be scheduled
    private int timeQuantum;      // Time quantum for the round-robin scheduling

    // Constructor: Pass task list to create an instance of this class
    public RoundRobin(List<Task> taskList) {
        this.taskList = new LinkedList<>(taskList);  // Copy task list for manipulation
    }

    // Set the time quantum outside of the constructor
    public void setTimeQuantum(int timeQuantum) {
        this.timeQuantum = timeQuantum;
    }

    @Override
    public void schedule() {
        while (!taskList.isEmpty()) {
            Task nextTask = pickNextTask();  // Get the next task

            if (nextTask != null) {
                int burstTime = nextTask.getBurst();  // Get the burst time of the task

                // If the burst time is greater than the time quantum
                if (burstTime > timeQuantum) {
                    CPU.run(nextTask, timeQuantum);  // Run task for time quantum
                    nextTask.setBurst(burstTime - timeQuantum);  // Reduce burst time by time quantum
                    taskList.add(nextTask);  // Re-add the task to the end of the list
                } else {
                    CPU.run(nextTask, burstTime);  // Run task for remaining burst time
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Task pickNextTask() {
        if (taskList.isEmpty()) {
            return null;  // No more tasks
        }

        return taskList.remove(0);  // Remove and return the first task in the list
    }
}

I have tried to change the constructor a few times. Initially, I had it calling two arguments. However, Project3.java only looks for one argument. So, I adjusted it and removed the quantum time outside of the constructor but the errors persist. I am not sure what else to do. I am fairly new to Java.
Project3.java (which cannot be adjusted)
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program3
{
    private static BufferedReader inFile = null;
    private static Scanner input = null;
    
    //***************************************************************
  //
  //  Method:       main
  // 
  //  Description:  The main method of the program
  //
  //  Parameters:   String array
  //
  //  Returns:      N/A 
  //
  //**************************************************************
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        Program3 obj = new Program3();
      
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        obj.developerInfo();
        obj.mainlineProcess();
    }
  
    //***************************************************************
  //
  //  Method:       mainlineProcess
  // 
  //  Description:  This method starts the program
  //
  //  Parameters:   None
  //
  //  Returns:      N/A
  //
  //**************************************************************
  public void mainlineProcess()
  {
        String scheduleName = null;
        String algorithmFilename = null;
        
        displayMessage();
        scheduleName = getUserInput("Enter the algorithm type: ");
        while (!scheduleName.equalsIgnoreCase("End"))
        { 
           algorithmFilename = getUserInput("Enter the schedule filename: ");
        
           openAlgorithmFile(algorithmFilename);
           List<Task> queue = createPopulateQueue();
           processAlgorithm(scheduleName, queue);

           try {
              if (inFile != null)
                 inFile.close();
           }
           catch (IOException exp)
           {
               System.err.println("Error - Input/Output Exception. Good Bye!");
               System.exit(1);
           }
           catch (Exception exp)
           {
               System.err.println("Error - Unknown Exception. Good Bye!");
               System.exit(1);
           }
           
           displayMessage();
           scheduleName = getUserInput("Enter the algorithm type or \"End\" to exit: ");
        }
        
      System.out.println("\nThanks for using the CPU scheduler - Bye!");
  }
  
    //***************************************************************
  //
  //  Method:       getUserInput
  // 
  //  Description:  This method gets the user input data
  //
  //  Parameters:   String prompt
  //
  //  Returns:      String
  //
  //**************************************************************
    public String getUserInput(String prompt)
    {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        
        String inputData = input.nextLine();

        return inputData;
    }
    
    //***************************************************************
  //
  //  Method:       openAlgorithmFile
  // 
  //  Description:  This opens the algorithm file
  //
  //  Parameters:   String input (File)
  //
  //  Returns:      N/A
  //
  //**************************************************************
    public void openAlgorithmFile(String input)
    {
      try {
            inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
        }
      catch (FileNotFoundException exp)
      {
          System.err.println("Error - The Schedule file was not found. Good Bye!");
          System.exit(1);
        }
  }
    
    //***************************************************************
  //
  //  Method:       openAlgorithmFile
  // 
  //  Description:  This method reads in the tasks and populates
    //                the ready queue 
  //
  //  Parameters:   None
  //
  //  Returns:      List<Task>
  //
  //**************************************************************
    public List<Task> createPopulateQueue()
    {
      // create the queue of tasks
      List<Task> queue = new ArrayList<>();
        
      String scheduleRecord;
        
      // read in the tasks and populate the ready queue   
      try {
            while ((scheduleRecord = inFile.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] tokens = scheduleRecord.split(",\\s*");
                queue.add(new Task(tokens[0], Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]), Integer.parseInt(tokens[2])));
            }
        }
      catch (IOException exp)
      {
          System.err.println("Error - Input/Output Exception. Good Bye!");
          System.exit(1);
        }
      catch (NumberFormatException exp)
      {
          System.err.println("Error - Number Format Exception. Good Bye!");
          System.exit(1);
        }
      catch (Exception exp)
      {
          System.err.println("Error - Unknown Exception. Good Bye!");
          System.exit(1);
        }
        
        return queue;
  }
  
    //***************************************************************
  //
  //  Method:       processAlgorithm
  // 
  //  Description:  A method to call the CPU schedule algorithms
  //
  //  Parameters:   String choice
    //                List<Task> queue
  //
  //  Returns:      N/A
  //
  //**************************************************************
    public void processAlgorithm(String choice, List<Task> queue)
    {
      Algorithm scheduler = null;

      switch(choice)
        {
          case "FCFS":
              scheduler = new FirstComeFirstServed(queue);
              break;
          case "SJF":
              scheduler = new ShortestJobFirst(queue);
              break;
          case "PRI":
              scheduler = new Priority(queue);
              break;
          case "RR":
              scheduler = new RoundRobin(queue);
              break;
          case "PRI-RR":
              scheduler = new PriorityRoundRobin(queue);
              break;
          default:
              
              System.err.println("Invalid algorithm. Good Bye!!");
              System.exit(0);
      }

      // start the scheduler
      scheduler.schedule();
  }
    
  //***************************************************************
  //
  //  Method:       displayMessage
  //
  //  Description:  This method displays a message to the screen
  //
  //  Parameters:   None
  //
  //  Returns:      N/A
  //
  //***************************************************************
  public void displayMessage()
  {
    System.out.println("Scheduling Algorithms");
    System.out.println("FCFS   - First-come, first-served scheduling");
    System.out.println("SJF    - Shortest-job-first scheduling");
    System.out.println("PRI    - Priority scheduling");
    System.out.println("RR     - Round-robin scheduling");
    System.out.println("PRI-RR - Priority with round-robin scheduling\n");
  }

Name of classes above: RoundRobin.java, PriorityRoundRobin.java

Looks ok. Would help to see Project3.java.

can you add program3.java along with package names for the above files, and program3 file...

Clean the project (delete all old class files). Then recompile. Make sure there are no conflicting versions of old source about

@forty-two I have added the Project3 code

My guess is that you imported classes with the same name but from different packages. Maybe you imported Task from one package in RoundRobin and imported Task from a different package in Program3. Is it possible for you to post some kind of [mcve]? At least include imports and package statements of your code.

@g00se I have already tried that but it did not change anything unfortunately.

@Abra The packages my professor provided were copy and pasted as classes into my project. I only wrote the five scheduling classes. They were created with the same package.

@itishrishikesh the package name is schedule, which I named when creating this project. I added other classes my professor provided by copy/pasting. I added Project3 code.

@itishrishikesh the package name is schedule I don't see any package specifiers in your code...

Maybe you imported java.awt.List instead of java.util.List ? Of-course we can't know if you don't post your code.

What Java version are you using? Is it modular, i.e. is it Java 9 or higher?

Hi Tiffany, welcome, I think the problem is that the class Task is not defined, so it does not accept the constructors, try to make a basic implementation, to see if the problem is solved, or at least a different one appears.

I have questions: 1) What's the timeQuantum field for? Never set. 2) The developerInfo method is missing in Program3.  Why?3) Why not use the standard javadoc tags, but instead some dated C style documentation? And an observation: During my 30ish years of Java experience (ok, 29), I have never stumbled on the Scanner class in "professional" code, only in academic exercises.

At first glance, it looks like everything should work.  Can you clarify the layout of your packages, and what's in each directory?  Or is everything in the same package and the same directory.  I'm wondering whether the Task that's referenced in Project3 is actually a different class from the Task that's referenced in the other two classes, so it would be good to know where Task has been defined.  It would also be good to see the import statements at the top of RoundRobin and PriorityRoundRobin to figure out which classes are referenced by List and by Task.

@Tiffany with the given code, I think the only reason you could be getting the constructor undefined error is that you have the PriorityRoundRobin and RoundRobin classes in another package than Program3. You might want to check the package names that are usually at the top of the file. Can you share your directory structure, and end-to-end code for the files you have added?
